# Difference between file capability and process capability

Tags: linux, posix, capabilities, setcap

I am trying to understand POSIX Capabilities. Sometimes, when reading the documentation they refer to file capabilities and sometimes to process capabilities.

What is the difference between file and process capabilities. What I understood is we assign capability to an executable by using setcap and then when it is running which is a process it will use that capabilities. Why additional process capabilities, as process is executable file in memory.

Answer (score 0):

File capabilities are set on an executable file with [setcap](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/setcap.8.html).

But other capabilities can be inherited from the launching process. This is described in the [Linux capabilites man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html):

```
   Inheritable
          This is a set of capabilities preserved across an execve(2).
          Inheritable capabilities remain inheritable when executing any
          program, and inheritable capabilities are added to the
          permitted set when executing a program that has the
          corresponding bits set in the file inheritable set.
```

Answer (score 0):

Serge E. Hallyn and I wrote [this paper](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/33528.pdf) on capabilities way back in 2008 just after we first implemented file capabilities in the Linux kernel. It contains some history, some theory and a whole bunch of simple worked examples that still do a reasonable hands-on walk through trying to explain how things work. I'm also trying harder to keep other reference and example material on the [Fully Capable](https://sites.google.com/site/fullycapable/) site.